# React Unmount Base Component In Render-Prop Pattern

Tags: reactjs

So Here is Some Sample Code Of What I Am Trying To Accomplish.

```
class NetworkCallHOC extends React.Component {

    makeNetworkCall = () => {
        this.setState({ isInNetworkCall: true });
        // Make Some Network Call;
        // On NetworkCall Complete;
        this.setState({ isInNetworkCall: false });
    }

    state = {
        isInNetworkCall: false,
        makeNetworkCall: this.makeNetworkCall,

    }
    render() {
        const { isInNetworkCall } = this.state;
        if (isInNetworkCall) {
            return // Some Loading screen;
        } else {
            const { children } = this.props;
            return children(this.state)
        }
    }
}
```

This 'Higher Order Render Prop' takes a component as a child and passes down a `function makeNetworkCall`.

Now when `makeNetworkCall` is called the child component is unmounted and after the network call is completed a new child component is mounted back again and all the lifecycle methods of the child component are called.

Is there a way to avoid re-creating the the child component in such a scenario.

Thanks Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to always render the children, along with an optional loading screen that would display on top of it.

Something like:

```
render() {
    const { isInNetworkCall } = this.state;
    const { children } = this.props;

    return <div>
        {children(this.state)}
        <Mask visible={isInNetworkCall}/>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Why not? In any case, I am pretty sure you need to render `children` unconditionally  if you don't want them to be unmounted.

Comment: Seems to make sense, I was hoping if one could store it using some key as  prop maybe ill just wait for an alternative approach.